# Poor Man's OAuth Grant - Review

Tags: oauth, oauth2, single-sign-on

A 3rd party company has requested that we implement single sign-on with them using the below approach. I'm familiar with OAuth grants and OIDC flows but this seems rather odd to me.

[image]

**The user has already logged into my application when this flow starts.**

```
a) Logged in user clicks a link to access the 3rd party system
b) My application creates a random code against the authenticated user with a time to live of 2 minutes and redirects the user to the 3rd party application with the code.
c) Redirect navigates the browser to the 3rd party application with the code.
d) 3rd party sends the code to my application. My application checks the code was one that was issued earlier and within the allocation time.
e) My application returns user information and the 3rd party treats this as Single Sign-On.
```

Stuff I'm uncomfortable about...

- Seems to be a poor mans OAuth implementation of the Authorization Code Grant
- No state parameter so
  there's risk of XSRF
- "3rd party" could be anyone
- Time to live on the
  code is a bit worrying
- There's no way to expire the user's session in the 3rd Party application. In OAuth, the tokens usually expire after a while.

Is there anything that's obviously bad about this implementation?
Do you think I'm potentially overreacting here and this is in fact suitable?

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is to strictly compare the Oauth2.0 rfc https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1 Authorization code Grant terminology and flow with the implementation. Bear in mind that some security issues related to Oauth2.0 implementations are also mentioned in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819 with apropriate countermesures.

> Seems to be a poor mans OAuth implementation of the Authorization Code Grant

There indeed seems to be some issues:

The *Ressource ower* is not clearly defined and/or confused with the *User-agent*

> a) Logged in user clicks a link to access the 3rd party system

In Oauth2.0:

> The client initiates the flow by directing the resource owner's
> user-agent to the authorization endpoint.  The client includes
> its client identifier, requested scope, local state, and a
> redirection URI to which the authorization server will send the
> user-agent back once access is granted (or denied).*

Here the *client* is the "3rd party", and the authorization endpoint "My application", if the "3rd party" is not issuing the client identifier, the scope and the local state to the browser, there is a high probability that the browser do the request with predefined params which is not what oauth2.0 was created for.

> No state parameter so there's risk of XSRF

> *(C)  Assuming the resource owner grants access, the authorization
> server redirects the user-agent back to the client using the
> redirection URI provided earlier (in the request or during
> client registration). The redirection URI includes an
> authorization code and **any local state** provided by the client
> earlier.*

CSRF could be mitigated with various techniques, but for that it is safer to follow oauth spec first and include a state parameter in the authorization request, since it SHOULD be used to protect against CSRF.

> "3rd party" could be anyone

Not really, in a case where the local state is missing and the redirection URI incorrect, the *the authorization server* should not redirect the user agent back to the client. A security issue here could be that the authorization server allow multiple URI's origin.

> Time to live on the code is a bit worrying
>
> There's no way to expire the user's session in the 3rd Party application. In OAuth, the tokens usually expire after a while.

One problem in some cases with OAuth tokens is that they could be stolen by attackers, but it is mitigated by the fact that the expires_in parameter (in seconds) is added to the fragment component of the redirection URI.

Most of the time if this param is omited the authorization server do  provide a default value. Here if the user session does not expire, you have to trust the 3rd party security to ensure that the session is not going to be stolen and usable.